# how to use complicate methods for update db like this?

Tags: java, database, methods

i'm absolute beginner ! and i don't know ho to use this kind of methods. please help me if you can.

i have a class named "DatabaseConnector"
inside of this class i have this method:

```
// Update Database function
public void UpdateNote(long id, String title, String note, String counts, String limits) {
    ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
    editCon.put(TITLE, title);
    editCon.put(NOTE, note);
    editCon.put(COUNTS, counts);
    editCon.put(LIMITS, limits);

    open();
    database.update(TABLE_NAME, editCon, ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}
```

i want to use this methods on another class but when i write this on my other class:

```
                DatabaseConnector.UpdateNote(rowID, null, null, null, null);
```

eclipse says that i should make this method static, and when i make this method Static, this parts of the method on "DatabaseConnector" class, wants to be static too :

```
    open();
    close();
```

and when i make them static too. the whole classes ruined and getting many errors...

now i have this questions:

1- how i can use this methods on my other classes without make them static or destroy the whole thing...

2- how should i write the method to update just one of the fields ? (the "COUNTS")...

i don't know what to write after the :

DatabaseConnector.UpdateNote(rowID, null, null, null, null);

Thank you all.

Comment: Why are you not able to use them in other classes? What is eclipse saying?

Comment: That's because you're calling the method on `DatabaseConnector` (the class). Instead, you should create an instance of that class (or use its factory to grab an instance) and make the call to `UpdateNote` using the instance - not the class itself. Try to search the code to see how this method is called in other places and do the same.

Comment: What is a *complicate method*? Is that related to [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)?

Comment: @iuliu.net : eclipse asking to turn them to static !

Comment: @alfasin = i will search for making an instance know.

Comment: @ Andreas : all of this is complicate for me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `UpdateNote()` is *not* static, then in order to use it, create an instance of the class:

```
DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(null);
```

and use it to call the method:

```
databaseConnector.UpdateNote(rowID, null, null, null, null);
```